# Problems when formatting and highlighting text with `column`

Tags: bash

I have a problema when issuing this command.

```bash
echo -e "Name|Age|Gender|Height|Weight
John|25|Male|180|75.5
Jane|30|Female|165|55.2
Bob|45|Male|175|85.1
Alice|35|Female|170|62.3
Dave|50|Male|185|92.8
Eve|40|Female|160|50.7
Tom|28|Male|175|70.5
Sue|42|Female|160|58.9
Mike|33|Male|190|81.2"  | sed -E '5s/^(.*)$/\x1b[1;46m\1\x1b[0m/' | column -t -s $'|' -o $' | ' -R 2,4,5
```

on my ubutu works fine, but on Oracle Linux 8.5 it does not.

```
Name            | Age | Gender | Height | Weight
John            | 25  | Male   | 180    | 75.5
Jane            | 30  | Female | 165    | 55.2
Bob             | 45  | Male   | 175    | 85.1
Alice | 35  | Female | 170    | 62.3           <-- This line gets HIGHLIGTHED but not indented
Dave            | 50  | Male   | 185    | 92.8
Eve             | 40  | Female | 160    | 50.7
Tom             | 28  | Male   | 175    | 70.5
Sue             | 42  | Female | 160    | 58.9
Mike            | 33  | Male   | 190    | 81.2
```

Any solution or idea

Comment: If you change `echo -e` to `printf '%b\n'` ? does it work as expected? but I think it is the `column` command if it is not indented.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the bash version in an Oracle Linux (`bash --version` shows 4.4.20 in my "lab") is counting the ANSI escape sequence characters when sizing the column which are substituted in the "Alice" line.  In the "Alice" line the escape sequences are consumed to produce the color and thus misaligned.

(You'll notice the "non-Alice" lines have much more spacing than would be required - since 'Alice' is the longest name something like 'John' should be `John  |` for example.)

So, to demonstrate it is shown that if you **swap the order of the commands the result is correct**:

### Before

(using the posted command in an Oracle Linux Luna Lab)

[image]

### After

(swapping the `sed` and `column` as in):

```
echo -e "Name|Age|Gender|Height|Weight
John|25|Male|180|75.5
Jane|30|Female|165|55.2
Bob|45|Male|175|85.1
Alice|35|Female|170|62.3
Dave|50|Male|185|92.8
Eve|40|Female|160|50.7
Tom|28|Male|175|70.5
Sue|42|Female|160|58.9
Mike|33|Male|190|81.2"  | column -t -s '|' -o ' | ' -R 2,4,5 | sed -E '5s/^(.*)$/\x1b[1;46m\1\x1b[0m/'
```

The desired output is generated.

[image]

---

A similar result can be obtained in ubuntu/bash (5.1.16) if the escape sequence is invalidated as in (with no highlighting since it was invalidated):

```
echo -e "Name|Age|Gender|Height|Weight
John|25|Male|180|75.5
Jane|30|Female|165|55.2
Bob|45|Male|175|85.1
Alice|35|Female|170|62.3
Dave|50|Male|185|92.8
Eve|40|Female|160|50.7
Tom|28|Male|175|70.5
Sue|42|Female|160|58.9
Mike|33|Male|190|81.2"  | sed -E '5s/^(.*)$/\x1b[1;46z\1\x1b[0m/' | column -t -s '|' -o ' | ' -R 2,4,5

Name        | Age | Gender | Height | Weight
John        |  25 | Male   |    180 |   75.5
Jane        |  30 | Female |    165 |   55.2
Bob         |  45 | Male   |    175 |   85.1
Alice |  35 | Female |    170 |   62.3
Dave        |  50 | Male   |    185 |   92.8
Eve         |  40 | Female |    160 |   50.7
Tom         |  28 | Male   |    175 |   70.5
Sue         |  42 | Female |    160 |   58.9
Mike        |  33 | Male   |    190 |   81.2
```